# Double joining of columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
ADP_4   G   G   G   C   G   G   G   G   G   A
ADP_5   G   G   G   A   G   G   G   G   G   A
ADP_3   G   G   G   C   G   G   G   G   G   A
```

Actually, I want to know, how can I join every two columns together (except the first column) like this one:

```
ADP_4   GG  GC  GG  GG  GA
ADP_5   GG  GA  GG  GG  GA
ADP_3   GG  GC  GG  GG  GA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby` along `axis=1`:

```
# print `col_blocks` to see what it does
col_blocks = (np.arange(df.shape[1])+1)//2
df.groupby(col_blocks, axis=1).sum()
```

Output:

```
       0   1   2   3   4   5
0  ADP_4  GG  GC  GG  GG  GA
1  ADP_5  GG  GA  GG  GG  GA
2  ADP_3  GG  GC  GG  GG  GA
```